# How to put images on top and side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am quite new at html and css. I currently have 4 images in which I need to put like this image here:

https://ibb.co/hNcUFx

My problem is the pictures are just displaying on top of each other going down.

```html
<div class="image123"> 
  <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img src="pizza.jpg" height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 1</p> 
  </div> 
  <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img class="middle-img" src="tacos.jpg"/ height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 2</p> 
  </div> <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img src="philly.jpg"/ height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 3</p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far to achieve output.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```css
.image123{
  max-width:750px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.imgContainer{
  float:left;
  width:48%;
  padding:10px 0px;
}
.imgContainer img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.imgContainer p{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:5px 0px;
  margin:5px 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .imgContainer{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image123"> 
  <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 1</p> 
  </div> 
  <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img class="middle-img" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 2</p> 
  </div> <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 3</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer"> 
    <img class="middle-img" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="200" width="75%"/> 
    <p>This is image 2</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay great this works but I forgot to add my last picture since Ive only had 3. How exactly would i add the last picture to fit in to the left of the cheese-steak photo?

Comment: The image is there but underneath the spot it has to fill. any help?

Comment: i have added 4th image,check now

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```css
.img-parent-box {
 display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-parent-box">
    <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
        <p>This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
        <p>This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
        <p>This is image 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
        <p>This is image 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the 3 images up from what the guy told me above but now im stuck with this since i forgot to add my last photo https://ibb.co/k4R9hc Any help?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand.  Can you add the site link ??

Answer (score 0):

The keys here is you need to style the div wrapping an image `display: inline-block;` & `width: 50%;`

Would you please to try this:

```css
.img-parent-box {
  font-size: 0; // this is a trick to fix bug of spacing
}

.img-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: initial; // this is to restore the font size of text of images
}
```

```html
<div class="img-parent-box">
 <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <p>This is image 1</p>
 </div>
 <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <p>This is image 2</p>
 </div>
 <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <p>This is image 3</p>
 </div>
 <div class="img-box"> <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <p>This is image 4</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** structure

```
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure>
      <img src="" alt="">
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

`.img-container` has `display: inline-block` and `.row` has `display: flex`.

### In total

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.img-container h4 {
  background: orange;
}

.img-container .row {
  display: flex;
}

.img-container figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container img {
  display: block;
}

.img-container figcaption {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <h4>Favorite meals</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/230x230" alt="">
      <figcaption>Pizza</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/230x230" alt="">
      <figcaption>Pizza</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/230x230" alt="">
      <figcaption>Pizza</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/230x230" alt="">
      <figcaption>Pizza</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/230x230" alt="">
      <figcaption>Pizza</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/230x230" alt="">
      <figcaption>Pizza</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```